# Difference between Virtual IP and loadbalancer?

Tags: networking, ip, load-balancing

I am a programmer and have been recently told to work on the Ops side.

I am struggling to understand the difference between Virtual IP and Load Balancer. Both look the same to me.

When I tried to read information online, it says Virtual IP has a range of hosts under it. And whenever any client hits the Virtual IP it assigns to one of the hosts under it.

As far as I know, a load balancer also does the same.

Can anyone tell me the difference between them?

Answer (score 2):

A virual IP is the address that the client uses to connect to the service. A load balancer is the device/mechanism that distributes the client connections to the real/backend servers.

Answer (score 1):

The virtual load balancer is a software-based load- balancing system that distributes incoming traffic across multiple targets such as servers, services, backend applications, etc. It’s software installed on the host machine that enables remote monitoring and controlling of the hosts. Virtual machines possess the same code that of hardware load balancers. A software version of a very complex hardware device, your virtual load balancer is the solution to a problem made obsolete by the advent of cloud computing.

On the other hand, hardware load balancers are on-premise, physical hardware machines that can serve a large amount of traffic. Unfortunately, one of the most significant drawbacks of hardware machines is limited flexibility.

Thanks to this [link](https://arraynetworks.com/tutorials/what-is-virtual-load-balancer/)